# How to style an image that is added dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made the html structure containing unordered lists, list items and attributes dynamically by a recursive function using jquery. Then I added an image inside the attribute tag. Now I want to style that image in a css file. The attribute tags also contains the name value from my json. I am showing all this in a context menu. I intend to show the image at the left side of the names. Currently the image that I add is appearing at the center and to the right of the name and the size of the image is too big as well. I want to adjust the position and size of the image. How can I do that in this case when I am adding the image dynamically? Here is the function that makes the html structure:

```
var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
        var item = $("<li>")
            .append(
        $("<a>", {
            title : itemData.name,
            html : itemData.name
        }).append($("<img>", {"src": "Boma_1_2/Boma.png"})));
        if (itemData.children) {
            var subList = $("<ul>");
            $.each(itemData.children, function () {
                subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
            });
            item.append(subList);
        }
        return item;
    };
```

Comment: You need to add class style to image?

Comment: @FerasAlSous yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to adjust the position and size of the image. How can I do that in this case when I am adding the image dynamically?

Add a CSS rule in your file with your position and size definitions. Lets assume your class name is `imgStyle`. Just add this class into your image tag during creation like below.

```
$("<img>", {"src": "Boma_1_2/Boma.png","class": "imgStyle"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add a class to it via `'<img class="my-image" src="'+src+'"/>'` and it will find the corresponding rule in your CSS and apply those, or you can also add it via jQuery:

```
var $img = $("<img>", {"src": "Boma_1_2/Boma.png"})
$img.css({width:'40px'})
$link.append($img)
```

First one is a bit cleaner.